# Disable item focus in ListView

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-arrayadapter

How can I disable the focus from an Item in a `ListView` when I click on it, so that there is no focus on click?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is your answer for disabling the focus of ListView. Override isEnabled(int position) method in your Adapter and return false.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
}
```

Comment: You also need to override the adapter method areAllItemsEnabled() and return false.

Answer (score 2):

override below method to disable/enable list rows...

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    //Write your code here......
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `listview.setItemsCanFocus(false)` this will disable items gaining focus at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just override a simple method in your class which extends the BaseAdapter.This will definitely
help you.Please don't forget to upvote.Enjoy.. :)

```
    @Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

add this snippet to your Adapter class.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position == 3) { // 3 is the disable list item here.
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```